# Avoid loop for Date add by day?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using Carbon to add number of days, it there a way to avoid using `for` and/or `while` loop?

Add the numbers of days (`$skipDayBy`) and add the number of days if found in `$excludeDatesPublic` or `$excludeDatesManual`?

For example working demo:

```
function calculateDate($skipDayBy = 0) {
    $excludeDatesPublic = ['2019-08-28'];
    $excludeDatesManual = ['2019-09-01'];
    $date = Carbon::now();

    for($i = 0; $i < $skipDayBy; $i++) {
        $date = $date->addDays(1);

        while(in_array($date->toDateString(), $excludeDatesPublic) || in_array($date->toDateString(), $excludeDatesManual))
        {
            $date = $date->addDays(1);
        }
    }

    return $date->toDateString();
}

echo calculateDate(4);
```

Returned 2019-09-02 as expected if today date is 2019-08-27.

Comment: Count how many of the dates in the excluded array are between the start and end dates. Then add that to the number of days in the range.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add that to the number of days in the range because each day, we need to check  if a date are in the excluded array, add up and then check the excluded array again. If you take a look at the `while` loop logic - `$date->addDays(1);` and check again in the excluded array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day that allows you to add days skipping holidays.

Alternatively, you can use the periods:

```
$skipDayBy = 5;
$excludeDatesPublic = ['2019-09-01'];
$excludeDatesManual = ['2019-09-04'];
$exclude = array_merge($excludeDatesPublic, $excludeDatesManual);

$date = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now(), $skipDayBy)
    ->addFilter(function (Carbon $date) use ($exclude) {
        return !in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $exclude);
    })
    ->calculateEnd();

var_dump($date); // 2019-09-06 18:50:17 if run at 2019-08-31 18:50:17
```

Answer (score -1):

With PHP shortly

```
$day='2019-12-12';


$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . " +4 days"));
echo $date;
```

Output

```
2019-12-16
```

Or u can use

```
$date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+4 days', strtotime($day)));
```